# Elasticsearch search for a value across multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

My purpose is to search for a value across multiple fields and return the count of these values ​​and the distinct value.

To do this I realized that I have to use the facets.

This is the database schema:

```
index:   
    analysis:   
        analyzer:
            custom_search_analyzer:
                type: custom
                tokenizer: standard
                filter   : [standard, snowball, lowercase, asciifolding]
            custom_index_analyzer:
                type: custom
                tokenizer: standard
                filter   : [standard, snowball, lowercase, asciifolding, custom_filter]
        filter:
            custom_filter:
                type: edgeNGram
                side: front
                min_gram: 1
                max_gram: 20

{
 "structure": {
   "properties": {
     "name": {"type": "string", "search_analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer", "index_analyzer": "custom_index_analyzer"},
     "locality": {"type": "string", "search_analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer", "index_analyzer": "custom_index_analyzer"},
     "province": {"type": "string", "search_analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer", "index_analyzer": "custom_index_analyzer"},
     "region": {"type": "string", "search_analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer", "index_analyzer": "custom_index_analyzer"}
   }
 }
}
```

and this is the query that I tried to use:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "locality": "bolo"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "region": "bolo"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "bolo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "region": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "region": "bolo"
        }
      }
    },
    "locality": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "locality": "bolo"
        }
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "name": "bolo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of all the tests I've done this is the query that is closest to my desired result, however, does not tell me the count of distinct field, I found it to count the total field.

For example, the above query returns the following result:

```
facets: {
       region: {
       _type: query
       count: 0
    }
    locality: {
       _type: query
       count: 2
    }
    name: {
       _type: query
       count: 0
    }
}
```

I would like to have a result like this (not so obviously written is correct, but does understand what I need):

```
facets: {
    ....
    locality: {
       _type: query
       "terms": [
           {"term": "Bologna", "count": 1},
           {"term": "Bolognano", "count": 1}
       ]

    }
```

How can I do?

I have already tried to use "terms" instead of "query" in the facets and put "index: not_analyzed" in the fields of research, but is only returned if I try the exact scope, not part of it!

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you will want to create facet filters to match just a single field and one facet that spans all the fields for the total.

Comment: Not exactly, I wish that for all facets not give me back the total count, but the content of the field that matches the search, and the count of any content found. As an example I wrote above. Such a thing is obtained using the facets `terms` instead of `query`, only `terms` finds only the exact match of the field!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using value count aggregation.
In value count aggregation , it provides you the number of unique terms.
While terms aggregation gives you the unique term and its document count.

I believe you are looking for the value count aggregation - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html